# UWP MediaCapture FocusAsync: the op is invalid

Tags: camera, uwp, qr-code, zxing

I use MediapCapture to scan QrCode. Here is my configuration:

```
var cameras = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
int cameraIndex = cameras.Count > 1 ? 1 : 0;
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[cameraIndex].Id };
settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;

await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
SetResolution();
_mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new Windows.Media.Devices.FocusSettings() { Mode = Windows.Media.Devices.FocusMode.Auto });
videoCapture.Source = _mediaCapture;
await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

And I have also a Tapped event on my CaptureElement which call the FocusAsync method:

```
await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

My issue is that I have sometimes (not always) an error when I try to focus (even if it's the first time I call it). This error is:

> The op is invalid

**EDIT:**

Here is my stack trace: (there is no inner exception)

> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at ProjectName.Views.QrCodeScannerPage.d__8.MoveNext()

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace

Comment: I added my stack trace in the post (for more lisibility)

Comment: Take a look at this example: [Capture device controls for photo and video capture]
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-device-controls-for-photo-and-video-capture) I think that await focusControl.UnlockAsync(); is missing

Comment: Okay, I finally choose to set auto focus (with the code of your example). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I choose to set auto focus from the following examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-device-controls-for-photo-and-video-capture